# Script to delete rows based on a time value in a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am trying to write a Script to delete rows based on the time value contained in a cell in Google Sheets, the value in the cell only has AM or PM time, there is no date. I have been experimenting but so far I have not been able to do it. Could someone please be so kind to give me an indication as to what conditions should be defined in the Script to meet this condition? The purpose behind this behavior is to show only posts that have been published within an hour. For this I will be automatically running the Script every hour. :)

Data Table:

| HOURS | MINUTES | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ADDRESS | POSTED AT | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 28.68062 | 14/9/1899 20:49:12 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mexico | 11:53:24 AM | ESSO"] |
| 1 | 0 | 28.68057 | 14/9/1899 20:49:08 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mexico | 1:01:47 PM | ESSO"] |
| 1 | 0 | 28.68069 | 14/9/1899 20:49:10 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mexico | 2:17:48 PM | ESSO"] |
| 0 | 2 | 28.68061 | 14/9/1899 20:49:13 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:36:55 PM | ESSO"] |
| 0 | 1 | 28.68068 | 14/9/1899 20:49:06 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:57:09 PM | SHELL"] |
| 1 | 1 | 28.68059 | -106.13241 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 9:23:42 PM | ESSO"] |
| 2 | 3 | 28.68074 | -106.13249 | Medina 8717, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 1:35:45 PM | SHELL"] |
| 2 | 1 | 28.68082 | -106.13253 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 1:43:11 PM | ESSO"] |
| 3 | 0 | 28.6805 | -106.13283 | Siria 2808, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 1:44:49 PM | ESSO"] |
| 8 | 59 | 28.64719014 | -106.0999422 | Blvrd Antonio Ortiz Mena 411, Unidad Presidentes, 31210 Chihuahua, Chih. | 1:44:49 PM | PEMEX |
| 1 | 0 | 28.68067 | -106.13255 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:59:42 PM | ESSO"] |
| 1 | 1 | 28.68069 | -106.13256 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 6:07:49 PM | BP"] |
| 2 | 1 | 28.68071 | -106.13255 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 4:42:28 PM | ESSO"] |

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet/demo sheet with a sample data along with your desired output as an example?

Comment: Here are a couple of images of an experimental Google Spreadsheet. The first one shows  the Spreadsheet before running the Script and the second shows the same Spreadsheet after the Script has been run.
Img 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ywf-Hr7c1neeMqXat1klhBCKwwuuI930/view?usp=sharing
Img: https://drive.google.com/file/d/130D68BFD3Nhi5rT7PkEp2sV9VlKP_qTh/view?usp=sharing
The idea behind the Script is to run it every hour to detect which posts are over an hour old thus deleting them and leaving the ones that are less than one hour old. Hope this explains what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This function will delete every thing older than about 2 hours.

```
function deleteRowBasedUponTime() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const dtv = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), new Date().getHours() - 2), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss a").split(/:| /).reduce((a, v, i, arr) => {
    if (i == 0) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 3600;
    if (i == 1) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 60;
    if (i == 2) a.sum += parseInt(v);
    if (i == 3 && v == "PM" && parseInt(arr[0]) != 12) a.sum += 43200;
    return a;
  }, { sum: 0, total: function () { return this.sum } }).total();
  Logger.log(dtv)
  let k = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let item = r[0];
    let itmv = r[0].split(/:| /).reduce((a, v, i, arr) => {
      if (i == 0) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 3600;
      if (i == 1) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 60;
      if (i == 2) a.sum += parseInt(v);
      if (i == 3 && v == "PM" && parseInt(arr[0]) != 12) a.sum += 43200;
      return a;
    }, { sum: 0, total: function () { return this.sum } }).total();
    if (itmv > dtv) {
      k.push(r)
    }
  });
  if (k && k.length > 0) {
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, k.length, k[0].length).setValues(k);
  }
}
```

**Timebased Trigger**

```
function onehourtrigger() {
  //this conditional ensures that you do not create more than one trigger for the same function
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "deleteRowBasedUponTime").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("deleteRowBasedUponTime").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```

You can goto to [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and using the search box find any function that you don't understand.

If it's a pure JavaScript function the go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Try it this way:

```
function deleteRowBasedUponTime() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Diesel");
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const dtv = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), new Date().getHours() - 2), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss a").split(/:| /).reduce((a, v, i, arr) => {
    if (i == 0) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 3600;
    if (i == 1) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 60;
    if (i == 2) a.sum += parseInt(v);
    if (i == 3 && v == "PM" && parseInt(arr[0]) != 12) a.sum += 43200;
    return a;
  }, { sum: 0, total: function () { return this.sum } }).total();
  Logger.log(dtv)
  let k = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let item = r[5];
    let itmv = r[5].split(/:| /).reduce((a, v, i, arr) => {
      if (i == 0) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 3600;
      if (i == 1) a.sum += parseInt(v) * 60;
      if (i == 2) a.sum += parseInt(v);
      if (i == 3 && v == "PM" && parseInt(arr[0]) != 12) a.sum += 43200;
      return a;
    }, { sum: 0, total: function () { return this.sum } }).total();
    if (itmv > dtv) {
      k.push(r)
    }
  });
  if (k && k.length > 0) {
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, k.length, k[0].length).setValues(k);
  }
}
```

I also set the format to time and went through each item of the list changing them to a more standardized format.

This is the resulting page after running the code:

| HOURS | MINUTES | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ADDRESS | POSTED AT | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 28.68061 | 14/9/1899 20:49:13 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:36:55 PM | ESSO"] |
| 0 | 1 | 28.68068 | 14/9/1899 20:49:06 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:57:09 PM | SHELL"] |
| 1 | 1 | 28.68059 | -106.13241 | Del Paraso 8716, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 9:23:42 PM | ESSO"] |
| 1 | 0 | 28.68067 | -106.13255 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 5:59:42 PM | ESSO"] |
| 1 | 1 | 28.68069 | -106.13256 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 6:07:49 PM | BP"] |
| 2 | 1 | 28.68071 | -106.13255 | Del Paraso 8720, Nuevo Paraso, 31123 Chihuahua, Chih., Mxico | 4:42:28 PM | ESSO"] |

Comment: Thank you very much for your response I've tried your code and it works though it is deleting all the posts in the Spreadsheet, even the ones that are less that two hours old, is there something I should change or that I am overlooking? Also when running the script I get this error message: Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I just copied and pasted into my editor and ran with the data that I had before and it works.

Comment: I solved the error problem.  It occurred because I guess nothing in your list  passed the  conditional test.  Please share a table of your data

Comment: Hi, here is the link to my table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hiv6HayiHz2HIAUeC-Tf2-rqbjrJKomEXmKxMuQwMC0/edit#gid=0

Comment: Had to change the column index from 0 to 5

Comment: Your expertise is amazing, I thank you very much for your help, your script is running great and I am just experimenting with it like tweaking time and so on. My programming language knowledge is very limited though with your help I'm sure learning new stuff.

Comment: The data going into my Spreadsheet is coming from different parts around the globe and looking at the code I’ve noticed that the script is calculating the time difference based on the SpreadsheetTimeZone so I wonder if someone posting some content is in a different time zone would that in anyway conflict with the logic of the Scrip?, i.e. someone in the U.K.  Posts at 10 AM and my time zone is -7 hrs. The script won’t be able to discern the difference so the post will be ignored and it won’t be deleted until the time difference is fulfilled. Is there any way to compensate this time difference?

Comment: The only place the script uses a time zone is in the calculation of the threshold which is relative to the spreadsheet that contains the script.  If you are importing data from other parts of the world then perhaps you should compensate for that in your code.